# Graticule padding in QGIS map copmposer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

I am trying to print a map like the image below. And I have a problem with grid and graticule.
I understand that the best way to have a grid (in UTM, meters) and a graticule (in GMS) is by adding both grids and changin the SRC to each one.

The problem with this method is that I can't find an option to add the padding marked in the photo.

The other way that I was trying is adding two Maps to the composer, the first one with the layers, and with the UTM grid in blue, and a second Map canvas backwards, in blank, showing the GMS graticule in WGS84.

I don't know if there is a better option to compose a simmilar map.

Does anybody know which would be the best method?

[image]

Comment: Looks like http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12211 - I'd keep an eye on that ticket

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I made something like this:

[image]

It's not beautiful, profesional, not even close to Your example cause I used zebra instead of interior ticks, but maybe this will help you somehow.

I used 5 (yes five) grids:

1. In km (EPSG:2180) with border type zebra and 18mm width - black
2. In degrees (4326) with border type zebra and 16mm width - blue (so it covered first grid and only 2mm is visible)
3. whatever with border type zebra and 14mm width (so it covered second grid and only 2mm is visible)
4. whatever with border type zebra and 13,8mm width but with all colours set to white so it covered everything from grid 3 border except 0,2mm black outline
5. just like grid 2 but without border only coordinates, and set distance to look good...

I know it's not an answer but I made it anyway while I was thinking about resolution so maybe it will help You. Better that then put it in rubbish...

You can see whole project how it is done [here on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkd5ywk414vg38n/test_grid.qgs?dl=0)